# Is it possible to trace the origin of an email sent from a browser operating in a VPN, running on windows 7 based local machine?

Tags: email, vpn

I have a Windows 7 machine with Citrix VPN installed. I work by accessing an authorised system located in the US by using the VPN.

I had sent an email using Gmail, working on Chrome, in the VPN. Will it be possible to trace/track the email from the receiever's end... I mean, will the receiver be able to know the exact path and hosts or machines that were used while the concerned mail was sent to him?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the email headers to see which meta information was sent along with the message.

More info: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en